How was the story of Exodus passed on accurately?
Some might question it that this kind of colossal story would be able to pass on accurately via oral tradition: for example older men telling this story to others among his own tribe Beside the fire.
My original intent was to ask that how is it possible that exodus story could be passed on to the next generation so accurately? Some might say that exodus story is a myth, because no-one can pass on this story so accurately as it is written in the Bible.

Well the first and most obvious option is that it was written down shortly after it happened. Alternatively God could have directly revealed it to some later prophet. Thirdly, ancient peoples in oral societies were much better at memorising and passing down their oral culture. But if all of those options are rejected, then I wouldn't see what grounds there even are for thinking that it is accurate.

@curiousdannii I think you should upgrade your comment to an answer.

Oral traditions are not exactly inaccurate either... consider the work of Roger Echo-Hawk, where Pawnee oral traditions document events that occurred during the last glaciation (11,000 years). Oral histories were not "changed" to change them was for that person keeping the story the ultimate sin possible.

It's not at all obvious why this is asking about Exodus (which is not oral tradition but was written down by its central participant), and not about Genesis.

I think the O.P should also consider that his claim that oral traditions are corrupted ( ie by Chinese whispers) is a little misleading. Chinese whispers usually influence the finer details, not the main story itself. The point is, Noah enterring an ark and the world being destroyed by a global flood are unlikely to have been corrupted by oral tradition. The ages of the indivudals, number of days of the flood, water levels, birds sent put at the end, rainbow...these things could he corrupted, but not the main event.

God spoke to Moses in a very particular way, so important were the words which needed to be recorded for posterity.

And the LORD spake unto Moses face to face, as a man speaketh unto his friend [Exodus 33:11 KJV]


With him (Moses) will I speak mouth to mouth, even apparently, and not in dark speeches; and the similitude of the LORD shall he behold: [Numbers 12:8 KJV]

Moses saw a representation and Moses heard words and, it is without doubt, Moses sat in the tabernacle, hour after hour, transcribing what he heard, as a man transcribes the words of another man, acting as a scribe.
These written records were faithfully preserved by a nation whose sole purpose was to receive and to testify to the whole earth, the word of God.
The evidence is within the documents themselves.
It is probable that Joshua witnessed these things for :

... his servant Joshua, the son of Nun, a young man, departed not out of the tabernacle. [Exodus 33:11 KJV]


Disbelief in the words of Moses, the written and recorded testimony to the whole earth, results in disbelief of all else that is of God.

If they hear not Moses and the prophets, neither will they be persuaded, though one rose from the dead. [Luke 16:31 KJV]


For had ye believed Moses, ye would have believed me: for he wrote of me. But if ye believe not his writings, how shall ye believe my words? [John 5:46 KJV]


One possibility, of course, is that God acted to ensure that the relevant accounts were accurately preserved.
However, even ignoring this likelihood, it is important to understand the influence of modern culture on our views of oral tradition. In an age when most people are literate and keeping written records is easy and cheap, we no longer have the need to maintain accurate recollections of events. Thus, we tend to judge oral tradition by our own experience, as if retelling of stories is like a large-scale game of "telephone" wherein each "copy" causes significant distortion.
Real oral tradition isn't like this. To be sure, not all stories were well preserved (the many, many variations on the story of Noah and the Flood are a good example), but nevertheless, people that relied on oral tradition were much more able to preserve knowledge than we typically believe to have been possible.
To understand this, it's necessary to recognize the difference between a children's game, tale telling, and preserving history. In the children's game, a message is told once, in a whisper with little to no possibility to correct errors. (The game is, in fact, designed to introduce error, as that's what makes it interesting.) Tales may be relayed from one teller to another, again after only a single hearing, and with little emphasis placed on accuracy. Preservation of oral history is completely different. We're told how ancient scribes had to receive extensive training, and of the exacting standards (and sometimes punishments) intended to ensure that their work was free of errors, but for some reason we don't think to apply these same standards to oral transmission. If your goal is to preserve history, however, it's only natural that you would employ similar principles; train extensively, practice over and over until you can recite something exactly as it was told to you, and whenever possible, use mnemonics to ensure that no degradation occurs. Modern anthropologists recognize that oral traditions are capable of passing down information over hundreds of generations with minimal corruption. A more general exploration of how oral tradition can be passed down reliably isn't really in scope for this SE, but as it applies to Scripture, what matters is that it's possible.
Even so, this assumes, without any real evidence, that no written records existed. It's not only possible that Adam, Noah and others all kept written records which were later consolidated by Moses, there are some differences in writing style that even suggest this to have been the case.
Now... all of the above is more applicable to Genesis than to Exodus, as in the case of Exodus, the events were written down by Moses (n.b. Exodus 24:4). Thus, for Exodus, there is no issue of accurate preservation; it was recorded in written form essentially as it was happening.

I didn't know that Exodus was written down by Moses. Though I haver read exodus at least once. I thought that it was first passed on orally as an oral tradition.

@alvoutila, while we aren't 100% certain, it's generally believed that Moses wrote exodus; see e.g. https://www.gotquestions.org/who-wrote-the-book-of-Exodus.html. There are dissenting opinions, but in my experience, a lot disagreements with Scriptural authorship (not just Exodus, but any book) come from people looking to discredit Scripture, so I'd take them with a hefty grain of salt. That said, it should also be noted that "wrote" may apply in the corporate sense, i.e. others may have been involved under Moses' oversight.

@alvoutila, not also that Jesus Himself suggests Mosaic authorship more than once, albeit not of Exodus specifically. https://answersingenesis.org/bible-characters/moses/evidence-mosaic-authorship-of-torah/ has some additional information, as does https://reasons.org/explore/blogs/voices/did-moses-write-the-torah-a-brief-positive-case-for-mosaic-authorship-part-1. There's quite a lot of information on the subject if you go poking around.

Most of the Pentateuch was written by Moses. Some minor additions, such as the death of Moses, were added, probably by Joshua. A handful or so of changes to the names of towns, such as "Rameses", "Dan" in Genesis 14:14, Ur "of the Chaldees" were made over succeeding centuries to help keep the understanding.
It used to be argued that Hebrew did not exist in written form as early as the time of Moses.  I believe Doug Petrovich has convincingly demonstrated that there is Hebrew written on pottery found in Egypt as early as 400 years before Moses ("The World's Oldest Alphabet" by Dr Doug Petrovich). Other early Hebrew is found written on rocks in the Sinai Peninsula.
The Bible chronologist, Rodger Young, has argued the book of Leviticus must have been completed by 1406 bc, which was when the Israelites entered the Promised Land.  The Seder Olam Rabbah tells us that Ezekiel 40:1 is writing about a Jubilee Year, and that it was the 17th Jubilee since entering the Land. Seeing as the Fall of Jerusalem was in 587 bc, this puts Ez 40:1 in 574 bc. Because a Jubilee Cycle was 49 years, the 17 Jubilees mean the Israelites must have entered the Promised Land in the year beginning Tishri 1407 bc.  Since they entered in the Spring, they entered in the year 1406 bc. See rcyoung.org for relevant article.
The point is this calculation matches exactly with the calculations of Valerius Coucke and the (slightly corrected) calculations of Edwin Thiele ("Mysterious Numbers of the Hebrew Kings") using the data in 1st and 2nd Kings, the Assyrian Eponym List of years, the Tyrian King Lists, and in the case of Valerius Coucke, other recorded dates, such as the year of the founding of Rome, the founding of Carthage and the Fall of Troy.  The fact that the calculation from Ez 40:1 matches to these other calculations to the same year exactly is strong evidence we can be certain of the year of entry into the Promised Land, and that the Jubilee system began from 1406 bc. It is also evidence the book of Leviticus, in which the Jubilee system is written, was written by 1407 bc.
And if Leviticus was written before 1406 bc, then why not all of the Pentateuch, including Exodus?
Finally, surely it is correct to add that God would have wanted the events of Exodus to have been accurately recorded. The view that it was not written at the time originates from sceptics.

"It used to be argued that Hebrew did not exist in written form as early as the time of Moses. [...] The view that [Exodus] was not written at the time originates from skeptics." Indeed! God Himself writes on stone tablets in Exodus 31:18. Writing is mentioned (commanded) in Exodus 17:14. Writing was known to Job (Job 19:23), who most likely predated Moses! The idea that writing was unknown can only be justified by assuming Scripture is false. In truth, it's entirely possible that Noah could write, and maybe even Adam!

@Matthew - Fully agree with you.

@Matthew (and I give you my permission to upvote my answer if you see fit!) Adam lived nearly a millenia, and surely he was one of the most intelligent men who has ever lived (if not the most after our Lord) - biology has been going downhill since the Fall - so the only hindrance to Adam developing a writing system would be the technology.. what to write with and what to write on.  The Korean language written form was developed by a single man without any prior development.

@Matthew - I might be wrong about the "single man" comment on the Korean Hangul script.. it was commissioned by a King of Korea, but may have involved a group of men.. the genius of its design suggests a united committee or maybe a single person.

Anyone with access to clay can leave a written record, especially if they know how to fire the clay. Soft metals also work, and Genesis records that Tubal-cain, who was likely born within Adam's lifetime, "was the forger of all instruments of bronze and iron". It doesn't even seem that improbable that some form of vellum and/or papyrus was known to Noah. The capacity to make papyrus was almost certainly lost post-Flood, so I don't know that we can say for certain it was invented later, as opposed to being recovered later.

There are literary techniques that can be used to make remembering stories or parts of stories. The technique that comes to mind first is chiasm, chiasmus

an inverted relationship between the syntactic elements of parallel phrases

This site has 49 examples, below are 2 examples from that site:
A(1:8-10)     Increasing Israel and Pharaoh's hatred       (ירבה)
     B(1:11)            Israelites were forced to labor
A'(1:12)      Increasing Israel and Egyptian hatred    (ירבה)
     B'(1:13-14)        Israelites were forced to labor

A(1:15-16)      Command to kill boys
    B(1:17)         The midwives feared God    (ותיראן)
        C(1:18-19)      Dialogue between Pharaoh and midwives
    B'(1:20-21)     The midwives feared God    (יראו) 
A'(1:22)        Command to kill boys

See also the book Exodus in Chiastic Structure, by Christine Miller
Oral tradition is not limited to Israelites/Exodus. There are many known techniques and examples of oral traditions being passed down. While there may be errors, the same can be said about written records.

Oral tradition could reliably pass on ancient tradition, this is shown in the Genesis stories which have their roots in ancient Mesopotamian epics which are many centuries older. The reliability of the Pentateuch lies in its theological or religious value rather than historical. We should not view the ancient literature through the anti-literary dichotomy of truth versus falsehood. The stories must have been written down very early, and they don't have to be passed on orally. The Mesopotamian clay tablets go back to 300 BC, so it is not hard to imagine that the Pentateuch was also written since its composition in some form.
The appropriate term you are looking for is historical, rather than accurate. The ancient writings should not be viewed through the anachronistic, post-Enlightenment, scientific, modern lens of historical writing, which has lost its literary narrative and is devoid of literary understanding.
The Catholic Study Bible, essay on Biblical History and Archaeology, by Ronald Simkins states:

The Bible contains much history: it is the product of history but not a book of history. The Bible is composed of many different formal types of literature (genres), and although many of the genres present a past, no literature in the Old Testament claims or presents itself to be a work of history. History, as first practiced by the classical historians Hecataeus, Herodotus, and Thucydides, entails not only the collecting of tales and traditions about the past but also the inquiry (which is what historia means) into the reliability of the traditions and plausibility of the tales. [...] The extent of history embedded in the biblical texts is also questioned because of the chronological gap between the biblical writers and the events that they purport to narrate. In most cases, the biblical writers did not witness the events they describe. They often lived centuries later and were dependent upon oral traditions and perhaps some written sources (the Bible refers to a number of written sources, discussed later) for the composition of their narratives of the past. The reliability of these sources and their use by the biblical writers is unknown. When no source material was available—for private events, for example—the biblical writers would simply fill in the historical void in their presentation of the past one way or another, ultimately by pure invention.
The biblical writers’ use of traditional literary and mythic patterns to tell their stories of Israel calls into question not only the narrative of the events but also the historical value of many details of the stories. This particular style of the biblical writers does not necessarily mean that no actual events lie beneath the narrative, but at the very least it indicates that the presentation of such events has been shaped to conform to a traditional interpretive framework. In other words, the meaning of such events as indicated by their presentation in the stories of Israel is more significant to the biblical writers than the historical reality of the events.

